# Issue with Tennis Ball Tracking

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, camera-calibration

As a practice on image and video processing, I'm working on Tennis Ball Tracking  project which presented at [Stanford's Digital Image Processing course webpage](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Project_Winter_1718/index.html). The presented program code seems to be completed, however lack of two images causes some errors.

> '../SharedData/courtTop.png'
>
> '../SharedData/netSide.png'

In fact, without these two image, the corner finding and subsequently trajectory simulation don't work.

To cope with the problem, is this possible to use similar images for that purpose or some other tricks are needed?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why not.
If the project revolves around a single video (taken from a single tennis match), than you can attempt to use one of the video frames to duplicate these missing images.
If it is a more general tennis tracking algorithm, just find suitable images from the internet.
In both cases make sure that the image format you are using is the same as the rest of the images provided with the project code.